# How to set selected attribute option on Select component

Tags: laravel-filament

I'm using Filament version v2.17.55 in Laravel 10.

Here is my code:

```
Forms\Components\Select::make('choice_id')
->label(__('Choices'))
->options([
    1 => 'Yes',
    0 => 'No'
])
->default(1),
```

I'm looking to select 'Yes' but I always have "Select an option" selected by default.

If not doable how to add JS on the component, so I can fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found, the placeholder selection need to be disabled:

```
 Forms\Components\Select::make('choice_id')
            ->label(__('Choices'))
            ->options([
                1 => 'Yes',
                0 => 'No'
            ])
            ->default(1)
            ->disablePlaceholderSelection(),
```

If searchable() is used it should be set to false `->searchable(false)`.
For new Filament versions you may need  `->selectablePlaceholder(false)` instead.